# jQuery iBox (lightbox clone) and IFRAMES

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hey there you lot, is there a way that I can open a lightbox (in this case iBox) from within an IFRAME and have the actual lightbox open in the Parent page?

*sigh* I am confusing myself here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if you have control of the parent page too.
If so you could either invoke methods directly using `parent.foo()` if on the same domain, or using e.g [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp) if on different domains.

Either way, you will have to load the correct scripts and css on the parent to do so.

Comment: So if my link to the iBox is: <a href="#save-to-book" rel="iBox" class="recipe-links" target="_parent">Save to Cookbook</a>, then how would I insert the parent.foo()?

Currently the actual iBox is appearing within the IFRAME :'(

Comment: You will have to manually call a method in the parent window, and in the parent have code that manually invokes the lightbox.

Comment: Sorry for being completely n00bish - How would I call a method for the PARENT page from the IFRAME'd page?

Comment: `parent.foo()` - parent is a reference to the iframes parent element. foo is the name of a function declared in the parents global scope.